# Understanding Python class variables

Tags: python

I am trying to understand python classes. I have simple class code named class1.py and given below,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

class Trial:

  def __init__(self):
     self.a = 0
     self.a = sys.argv[1]

  def xyz(self):
     n = 10
     print self.a

     if n > self.a:
         print "Found number"

ob = Trial()
ob.xyz()
```

when i run above code as

```
python class1.py 1
```

it gives output only number 1 and does not print "Found Number". It should print "Found number" as 10 > 1 condition is true. please, help me to understand this code.

Comment: You're comparing integer with string.

Comment: when you pass argument it stores in sys.argv list as string, so you need to do `self.a = int(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: can you plz write here corrected code.

Comment: also, I'd like to point out that by doing `self.a = 0` and immediately below assigning `self.a = int(sys.argv[1])`, the first statement has absolutely no meaning.

Comment: Why negative votes? I think i have provided every information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
self.a = sys.argv[1]
```

by:

```
self.a = int(sys.argv[1])
```